# Kbuild - build multiple .o files from same .c file

Tags: linux, makefile, driver, kbuild

I have two drivers that share some of the same source files.  Most of the shared code is identical but there are a few pieces that I need to `ifdef` for a specific driver.  I would like these files to reside in the same directory so I don't have duplicate source code files. I therefore need to be able to build .o files more than once and be able to send `-Dvariable` when building them.

My current attempt for myusb.ko:

```
obj-$(CONFIG_DRIVER_USB) += myusb.o
myusb-y            += my_main_usb.o
myusb-y            += my_init.o

$(obj)/my_main_usb.o: $(src)/my_main.c
    $(CC) -DWHICH=USB $< -o $@
```

which does attempt to build my_main_usb.o from my_main.c but does not have any of the normal `CFLAGS`, includes, etc.

If I can get this to work, I can then do similar for mysdio.ko

Is this the correct approach?

Comment: This is unclear. You have a set of source files (e.g. `my_main.c`), and you wish to build *two* sets of object files from them, according to a variable. Do you want to give them different names (e.g. `my_main_usb.o` and `my_main_other.o`), or put them in different directories (e.g. `obj_usb/my_main.o` and `obj_other/my_main.o`), or what?

Comment: I was able to get what I want with:
`
obj-$(CONFIG_DRIVER_USB) += myusb.o
myusb-y            += my_main_xxxusb.o
myusb-y            += my_init.o

%-xxxusb.o: %.c
       $(CC) $(c_flags) -DUSB -c -o $@ $<

obj-$(CONFIG_DRIVER_SDIO) += mysd.o
mysd-y            += my_main_xxxsd.o
mysd-y            += my_init.o

%-xxxsd.o: %.c
       $(CC) $(c_flags) -DSD -c -o $@ $<
`
thanks!

Comment: I've rolled-back your edit adding an answer in your Question. I'm glad you found a solution to your problem. However, an actual answer/solution should **not** be edited into your Question. In general, you should [edit] the Question to *clarify the Question*, but not to include an Answer within the Question. I put the answer in the Answer you created. You should be able to indicate it's the answer that helped you by accepting it (IIRC, there's a required 48 hour delay prior being able to accept your own Answer). Just so you know, [answering your own question is encouraged](/help/self-answer).

Comment: thanks for setting me straight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get what I want with:

```
obj-$(CONFIG_DRIVER_USB) += myusb.o
myusb-y            += my_main_xxxusb.o
myusb-y            += my_init.o

%-xxxusb.o: %.c
       $(CC) $(c_flags) -DUSB -c -o $@ $<

obj-$(CONFIG_DRIVER_SDIO) += mysd.o
mysd-y            += my_main_xxxsd.o
mysd-y            += my_init.o

%-xxxsd.o: %.c
       $(CC) $(c_flags) -DSD -c -o $@ $<
```